# Is there any file password protection (NTFS)? I want to Hide & prevent of use!

Tags: password

Is there any file password protection (NTFS)? I want to Hide & prevent of use!
I know that I can hide with ".folder", but I want something whithout changing the name and I can Hide or Password it. File is on Windows partition.
Thanks for answers.

Comment: Hide and prevent use from who?

Comment: The question is rather vague. Do you want to hide files from Windows or from Ubuntu users, or both?

Comment: For both windows and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have a file that you need to access, but only after a password has unlocked it, correct?

If so, I would strongly suggest you look at using [TrueCrypt - http://www.truecrypt.org/](http://www.truecrypt.org/).  You can install it in both Windows and Ubuntu and use the same password to unlock the same file on either system.

The only drawback to your situation is that you specifically state "file password protection" but TrueCrypt creates a volume with the encrypted contents inside the volume.

Comment: I actually downloaded, but I just want to hide folder on both windows and Ubuntu. Thanks for answer.

Comment: @Ali You can make the folder hidden in Windows, and make its name start with a `.` so it's hidden in Ubuntu too. But [it can still be discovered easily](http://askubuntu.com/a/147455/22949) by a user on either system.

Comment: Yeah Thanks, True-crypt working on both windows & Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You can use gpg to encrypt files with symmetric encryption (using a password).
You will be able to decrypt these on windows if you need to using pgp or gpg for windows.

You can do this on the command line like so:

```
gpg -c blah.txt
```

There is a plugin for nautilus that allows for encryption and decryption of files, however it only supports asymmetric encryption (it will decrypt symmetric however), which is not particularly useful for encrypting files on the same hard drive as they keys are held IMO.

If you want to use that anyway it's called seahorse-nautilus and it's in the repo.

Answer (score 1):

Just hiding a file doesn't keep anybody from accessing it. On both Ubuntu and Windows, hidden files can be shown easily in the graphical file browser and in the command-line. In Ubuntu, the Nautilus file browser will show such files if you go to `View` > `Show Hidden Files` (or just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>).

If the problem is that you want to keep people from reading the contents of a file even if they have access to the file (which includes if they stole your computer or your hard drive), you should use encryption; other answers here explain some options for that.

If the problem is that NTFS partitions are mounted in Ubuntu so that all users on your Ubuntu system have full access to them, and you want to control access to individual files and folders on your NTFS volume the same as they are controlled in Windows, then what you need to do is to mount your NTFS partition with support for NTFS permissions.

To learn how to do that, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/74851/22949) and [this documentation](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/ownership-and-permissions/). It's a bit complicated, but quite doable. If you have trouble, feel free to post a question asking for help.